# can not update composer in symfony2

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php

I cloned new project from a Git project that uses Symfony 2. Then I tried to update Composer:

```
$ composer update   
Loading composer repositories with package information   
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out    
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date    
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)   
Generating autoload files   

  [ErrorException]                                                             
  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/alipay_web/vendor/composer/autoload_namespa  ces.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

So could anyone please tell me what should I do?

Comment: how have you installed you composer? globally or something else ?

Comment: I have installed composer globally.

Comment: Looks like your server is having connectivity issues (the connection to the packagist server times out). It might be a DNS/routing issue. What happens when you run `curl https://packagist.org/packages.json`? Does that return anything at all?

Comment: Please attach the output of `composer diagnose`. My first guess was a permissions issue, but it looks more like a net/connectivity problem.

Comment: I solved the problem. thanks to all for helping me. Problem was in proxy settings. terminal uses previous proxy settings although i remove it. Then i used dongle and reinstalled composer.